# How to enable wifi data tethering on Android KitKat devices?

Tags: wifi, android-4.4-kitkat, tethering

I am using Moto e with android kitkat 4.4.4 version.After some searching on google I found that tehering is disabled to support mobile operators for their data plans.

> I am able to use mobile data through usb tethering and bluetooth tethering.

Comment: Simple explanation here:  https://pmf.silvrback.com/fixing-tethering-on-android-kitkat

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution for this problem and it help me to re-enable wifi data tethering on my kitkat phone.

1. Download Android SDK (Developer Toolkit).
2. Download the USB drivers for your phone.
3. Enable "Developer Options" and "Usb debbugging".
4. From command prompt, Change directory to "android-sdk\platform-tools"
5. Type Command

> adb shell content insert --uri content://settings/global --bind
>   name:s:tether_dun_required --bind value:i:0

6. To verify,type Command

> adb shell content query --uri content://settings/global --where
>   "name='tether_dun_required' AND value=0"

7. Retstart your phone and check wifi tethering.

If you want the instructions in details please follow this [post](http://forums.redflagdeals.com/how-fix-data-tethering-android-kitkat-devices-tbaytel-any-wireless-co-1436409/) in the forum.

Comment: The same result may be achieved using the command:adb shell settings put global tether_dun_required 0